# SQL Query to Find Duplicate form two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `ganadordia` and `ganadornoche` with numbers in column `winNumber` for both tables. I would like to create a new table based on the duplicated numbers found in each table

However, I'm encountering an issue: `winNumber` is creating an additional duplicate. For example, if I have two numbers 101 instead of getting only 2 I get 3

```
SELECT Distinct  ganadoresdia.winNumber as 'Winner Day',ganadoresdia.Month as 'Month Day', ganadoresnoche.winNumber as ' Winner Night',
ganadoresnoche.month as 'Month Night'
FROM ganadoresdia, ganadoresnoche
where ganadoresnoche.winNumber = ganadoresdia.winNumber
ORDER BY ganadoresdia.winNumber asc
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? it show 13 instead of 8
[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56nHI.png)

This is the result for `ganadornoche`it should only display 5
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOCEe.png)

This is the result for `ganadordia` it should only display 3
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv5c1.png)

Comment: For a join to not increase the number of rows (or technically, increase the cardinality of the value(s) from the fields in the join condition in the final result) the field(s) used in the join condition must be unique in at least one of the tables. From this query I can't quite understand what the real purpose of this is, some sample data would help. But in any case, if WinNumber is not unique in ganadoredia or noche you must aggregate/distinct/add another column to the join.

Comment: @Error_2646

Correct the number in `winNumber` are not unique because they can be repeated multiple times.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? In a perfect world what result would you see? Once you determine that, enter it in as sample data with the expected result in the post and you'll get more specific answers.

Comment: By `duplicated numbers found in each table` it's not clear to me what constitutes a duplicate. Is a number a duplicate if it appears in the same table more than once, if it appears in both tables, or something else?

Comment: @GregPavlik I attached an example of the database.

Comment: @Error_2646 I added some pictures that might help.

Comment: Please do not post image for data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample I assume what you actually want to do is union the data rather than join (5+3=8). To do a join you need a primary:foreign key relationship, which you don't seem have.

```
SELECT 'day' as day_night_indicator,
       winNumber,
       month
  FROM ganadoresdia
 UNION
SELECT 'night' as day_night_indicator,
       winNumber,
       month
  FROM ganadoresnoche
```